# How to create CSV output from JSON?

Tags: json, powershell, csv

My JSON query returns weather data that I would like to parse using powershell. I want to delete all unnecessary items and export the final file to CSV or txt.

```psh
$json = Get-Content -Raw $path | ConvertFrom-Json #get JSON object from directory and convert to powershell object
$hourly = $json.hourly_forecast
$FCTTIME = $hourly.FCTTIME
$pretty = $FCTTIME | Select pretty

$temp = $hourly.temp
$eng = $temp | Select english

$parsed = $eng, $pretty
```

It seems to work okay but when I output `$parsed` in CSV it has the object properties rather than the values of `$eng` and `$pretty`. Is there any easier way to parse JSON files or another way I can combine the arrays in the last step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expand the properties. Also, [`Export-Csv`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx) exports the properties of objects, not the values of an array. Something like this should work:

```psh
Get-Content -Raw $path |
  ConvertFrom-Json |
  select -Expand hourly_forecast |
  select @{n='Pretty';e={$_.FCTTIME | select -Expand pretty}},
         @{n='English';e={$_.temp | select -Expand english}} |
  Export-Csv 'C:\output.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: This looks like it almost works but the 'pretty' column is left empty on the output?

Comment: @hwustrack Sorry, typo. There was a dot missing between `$_` and `FCTTIME`. Fixed.